# How do I fix 1/4 of the left column not being displayed within font manager?

Tags: linux, xfce

I installed the font manager, and the left column is not being displayed in entirety.  I tried to resize the window, etc... No quick fix.

Here is a screenshot.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to a quick Google this Issue has already been added to the Font Manager Repository on Github (take a look here: [Layout: cover left sidebar on the right side when too small](https://github.com/FontManager/master/issues/50))

Actually it seems to be related to a "GTK+ Issue kinda Thingy which may be not an Issue in the Eyes of the GTK+ Devs"

So like written in the Github Issue i guess your best Option is to wait and deal with it. Unless you have access on the Sourcecode and know how to code.